# Is sensitive store data stored in BigCommerce template?

Tags: bigcommerce

Recently a visitor asked if i would sell my BigCommerce template to them by downloading the files and sending them the zip file. I'm willing to sell it but I wanted to first ask if anyone knows if there is any sensitive information stored in the custom template files that my store is currently using such as payment gateway or customer info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer without knowing more about your theme.  Generally speaking, themes based on Bigcommerce's Blueprint framework should have nothing sensitive or identifiable in the theme files themselves.  With that said, the only one who can be 100% sure with regards to your custom theme is you.  Have you added any third-party JavaScript embed snippets directly to your theme files?  These often include a reference to an ID that'd be specific to your store.  Ditto any HTML provided by third-party form services a-la Wufoo.  I'd double check every place in the theme where you may have added anything that interacts with an external service or API.